# Is there a JavaScript implementation of LESS for CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, less

I have a need to do variable substitution at least in CSS from JavaScript (let's ignore whether that's client or server side for the moment). Ideally, I'd use the [LESS syntax](http://lesscss.org/docs.html) which offers more features than just variable substitution. Has anyone found a JS implementation of LESS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The next version of LESS is written in JavaScript. I believe it will work from the client or server. I don't know how well it works right now, but it could be worth looking into.

The source code is at http://github.com/cloudhead/less.js.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize that LESS is being ported to JS. Looks great!